How the K-topology generates a topology for real line?
In Munkres' we define the K-topology as follows:
Let $K$ denote the set of all numbers of the form $1 / n$, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, and let $\mathscr{B}^{\prime \prime}$ be the collection of all open intervals $(a, b)$, along with all sets of the form $(a, b)-K$. The topology generated by $\mathscr{B}^{\prime \prime}$ will be called the $\boldsymbol{K}$-topology on $\mathbb{R}$. When $\mathbb{R}$ is given this topology, we denote it by $\mathbb{R}_{K}$.
So, our basis elements don't include the reals in the form of $1/n$.
We have $\frac{1}{3}\in \mathbb{R}$ but there is no basis elements which contains $\frac{1}{3}$ in it(Because, they were omitted when we take tke difference with $K$).
By the defintion of basis, we can say that this definition basis doesnt give us a topology for $\mathbb{R}$.
Am I misunderstanding the concept of base? Or did I not understand the definition of these new base elements?
Definition of basis:
If $X$ is a set, a basis for a topology on $X$ is a collection $\mathscr{B}$ of subsets of $X$ (called basis elements) such that
(1) For each $x \in X$, there is at least one basis element $B$ containing $x$.
(2) If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$, then there is a basis element $B_{3}$ containing $x$ such that $B_{3} \subset B_{1} \cap B_{2}$.

You forgot that $(a,b)$ is also a basis element for each $a$ and $b$. Thus $(0,2)$ contains each point of $K$

So, we have all elements in the form of $(a,b)$ and additionally elements in the form of $(a,b)-K$ as our basis elements. Am I right?

That is what you quoted: "let $\mathscr{B}^{\prime \prime}$ be the collection of all open intervals $(a, b)$, along with all sets of the form $(a, b)-K$".

Yeah, you are right. I just misunderstood what I read. Thank you!
